# When i was trying to read input from the user into a List ,but after reading the first number from user i'm getting an exception

Tags: c#, generics, compilation

When i was trying to read input from the user it throws an exception of type

> 'System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException'

after reading the first number from user.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        // Variable Declaration
        List<int> Marks = new List<int>();
        int i, Sum = 0, Avg;
        for (i = 0; i <= 3; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Marks of Subject :");

             **I'm getting an Exception here
             It just reads one subjects marks and then throws exception

            Marks[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

              Sum = Sum + Marks[i];**
        }


        Avg = Sum / 4;
        Console.WriteLine("Your Total is  {0} \n\nAverage is   {1}", Sum, Avg);
        Console.ReadLine();

    }
}
}
```

[This is the Exception i'm getting]

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WxQa5.png)

Comment: You're trying to index the list `Marks` without adding any items to it. I'd suspect you are looking for `Marks.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));`

Comment: You're mixing arrays and lists.

Comment: Thank u for the help.

Answer (score 2):

When you enter your `for` loop the list `Marks` is empty.
So on your first iteration, `i` equals 0, but you can't set `Marks[i]` because there is no `Marks[0]`. It's an empty collection.

Perhaps what you want instead of

```
Marks[i] = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
```

is

```
Marks.Add(int.Parse(Console.ReadLine()));
```

To simplify a little bit:

```
var mark = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
Marks.Add(mark);
Sum = Sum + mark;
```

Or instead of adding each mark to `Sum` one at a time you could just wait until the `for` loop finishes and do

```
Sum = Marks.Sum();
```